# LUIS is not updating the Intent "score" for one word

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am facing a weird issue with LUIS. I have a keyword "infopedia" which should fall in some other Intent but JSON is showing the Top Score for "None" Intent.

I tried to add the utterance, it's showing me fine when I am adding in utterance. But whenever I am querying that word, it's showing me "None" intent for the same.

Could you please help me how I can update the Score for particular intent? in order to get the correct result.

[New utterances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHXN4.png)

[Review labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOBmE.png)

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYnqK.png)

**Suggest:**
[image: Suggest]

```
{
  "query": "infopedia",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "None",
    "score": 0.36293143
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.36293143
    },
    {
      "intent": "TrendingItems",
      "score": 0.262885571
    },
    {
      "intent": "Thanks",
      "score": 0.258188784
    },
    {
      "intent": "Hi",
      "score": 0.1920927
    },
    {
      "intent": "WhatsUp",
      "score": 0.08811139
    },
    {
      "intent": "Bye",
      "score": 0.006096343
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "infopedia",
      "type": "Keyword",
      "startIndex": 0,
      "endIndex": 8,
      "score": 0.659655631
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you trained your model after adding the new utterances?

Comment: Yes, I trained the model

Comment: Did you publish the model? Another note, I see that all intent scores are so close (0.26, 0.25, 0.19, 0.36). That means that you model needs more examples to be able to discriminate between intents.

Comment: @VirendraKumar You added 'infopedia' as an entity! not as an intent! So, it does not change the score of intents!